# Unable to format m-2 type ssd drive

Tags: windows-10, ssd, formatting

It's a Samsung PM961 256gb socket m-2 drive. My mobo BIOS sees it, but the Windows 10 storage/disc management tool cannot format it. It sees it initially but is unable to format it either as MBR or GPT. Once it goes past this stage the drive disappears from the "window" view. On reboot, the drive is visible in BIOS though. 
Should I return it or am I missing something?

Comment: Boot onto a WinPE disk or a Windows Setup disk and type "Diskpart" into CMD. Then look at the "cleandisk" command. Do a clean disk and maybe try and reformat as MBR/GPT whilst in diskpart. If not, do a cleandisk and reboot into Windows and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I will try that when I can, I don't have that pc with me at present.

Comment: So I used Diskpart, essentially it wasn't successful because the drive only showed for a short time (in List Disk) then disappeared from any further viewing attempt via the command line. I've returned the drive to the vendor. Thanks for the advice anyway Bitten Fleax.